# Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a Kubernetes service account:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl create namespace devops-tools
Please enter Username: kubernetes
Please enter Password: Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$
```

But I get this error. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: I'd check the `kubeconfig` first. It seems to me that you have an issue with it.

Comment: how I can list the config in kubeconfig?

Comment: You should be looking at `$HOME/.kube/config`.  I don't remember when was the last time I saw user/password authentication to `kube-apiserver`. How have you created this cluster and retrieved the credentials?

Comment: I used this tutorial https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-22-04/

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes indicates that it has identified you as system:anonymous (unkown)

Please see this part of the Kubernetes documentation that discusses the different authentication methods https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/

For username and password authentication to work, you should look at the Static Password File section.

Comment: hm.. I don't find this part. Can you guide me in details, please?

Comment: I just took a look at the blog post you followed, I'm not sure but something that comes to mind is to export the kubeconfig env var 

```export KUBECONFIG= $HOME/.kube/config 
```

 ```echo "export KUBECONFIG= $HOME/.kube/config" | tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: ok, this solves the issue. I tried to create a new user but at the end I don't get anything for a secret value: https://pastebin.com/s48Kitkq  Any idea why?